# how to replace key-value pair to another key-value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array with an arbitrary number of arrays.

The array is called `charge_codes`.

**print_r( $charge_codes )**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [charge_code] => 21
            [amount] => 134.57
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [charge_code] => 4
            [amount] => 8.05
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [charge_code] => 23
            [amount] => 1.68
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [charge_code] => 62
            [amount] => 134.12
        )

)
```

I am trying to loop through the array and find the amount for charge code 62 and assign it to the amount for charge code 21. Once The amount has been assigned to charge code 21, I need to remove the array with charge code 62.

**Result I am wanting**

```
Array
(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [charge_code] => 21
                [amount] => 134.12
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [charge_code] => 4
                [amount] => 8.05
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [charge_code] => 23
                [amount] => 1.68
            ) 

    )
```

Should i loop through using `foreach( $charge_codes as $key = > $value )` ?

Comment: Looping with key and value won't help, but using a first loop to find the value to be reassigned and a second loop to reassign should do the job

Comment: are the charge codes unique? Will you have multiple instances in an array of charge_code 62?

Comment: charge_code 62 may not always exist. The amount for charge code 21 only needs to be replaced if charge code 62 exists.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $change_key = 0;
    $amount = 0;

    foreach($charge_codes as $key=>$value){
     if($value["charge_code"] == 21)
     {
      $change_key = $key;
     }
     if($value["charge_code"] == 62)
     {
      $amount = $value["amount"];
      unset($charge_codes[$key]);
     }
    }

    if($amount != 0){
     $charge_codes[$change_key]["amount"] = $amount;
    }
    print_r($charge_codes);
```

Try this code.

Comment: well if '$value["charge_code"]' doesn't equal 21, then  '$charge_codes[0]["amount"]' will be set to 0 regardless?

Comment: I have write my code based on this condition. - charge_code 62 may not always exist. The amount for charge code 21 only needs to be replaced if charge code 62 exists. @Juakali92

Comment: Yes but now I have edited my question based on OP comment on the question.

Comment: @SmitRaval thanks! Worked perfectly. Will this code still work if the charge codes are in a different order?

Comment: Yes it will work for any order. Make sure there must be a charge_code 21 in an array. @IbrahimHafiji

Comment: charge code 21 will not always be in the array, but I have copied the if statement for the charge code 21 and made the same one with charge code 20 and 11. One of them will always be in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = [
    ["charge_code" => 21, "amount" => 134.57],
    ["charge_code" => 4, "amount" => 8.05],
    ["charge_code" => 23, "amount" => 1.68],
    ["charge_code" => 62, "amount" => 134.12] 
];

/**
* @Function to search the index from array
*
* @Args: charge code
*
* @Returns: null | index
*/
function searchIndexByChargeCode($chargeCode) {
    global $arr;
    foreach ($arr as $index=>$vals) {
        if (!empty($vals["charge_code"])) {
            if ($vals["charge_code"] == $chargeCode) {
                return $index;
            }
        }
    }
    return null; 
}

$index62 = searchIndexByChargeCode(62);
$index21 = searchIndexByChargeCode(21);
$arr[$index21]["amount"] = $arr[$index62]["amount"];
unset($arr[$index62]); 
?>
```